# Decoupling two classes for notifications

Tags: c++, algorithm, events, poco

I just stared looking into Poco framework. I have another underlying framework that already was using Poco framework and abstracting some parts of it to make it even more easier.

I want to explain the problem with a simple scenario:
Consider that I have a rectangle shape object in my program. The shape has private `hit Testing` methods inside to it and on hit testing being true for a certain time, I had to fire a function in another class i.e my `Fountain` class.

I don't need to pass any specific object information of shape to the function in the `Fountation` class. My framework already gives me some functionaliy of `NotifyEvent` and `AddListener`. If I would have gone by this approach, I would have an event inside my shape class which would be subscribed in fountain by `Add Listener` (object if shape is passed) and the event *notified* from within the shape class.

Now, with the Poco notification center, instead of passing the shape object reference to foundation class, I'll be passing the `NotificationCenter` reference to the second class. The `fountain` class will then have an observer and the observer will be notified from shape by `postNotification()`
The only difference that I see here between the two approaches is not passing the specific object information. 
I am just a fresher dev here trying to learn good coding practices whenever possible, and not clear about the decoupling here. How are the two classes decoupled here? (because I am not passing `shape` object and just using `notificationcenter` object?)

EDIT: Adding to the above question. Let's say I have 10 other classes which have to listen to a certain notification, so I'll have to pass the reference of the `Notification Center` to all these classes as well? That way only I'll be able to add an observer for the notification center in my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes. If the `Fountain` class only knows about the `NotificationCenter`, then it is not coupled to the shape (`Rectangle` or others) anymore. This assumes that the notification posted by the shapes is also not dependent on the object that fires it.

Edit: The reply to your edit is yes, you'll need to call the `addObserver` method with each object that needs notifications

Comment: Additional query as well. So, I can use the same Notification sort of globally to postNotifications from other objects as well? Let's say positing Notification from `Fountain class` for some other class. Is this also correct? 
P.S Can you recommend some text book where I can have a better idea while I write the programs to actually know what's good, bad or better?

Comment: Yes, the Fountain class could also use the notification system. I would be careful though about how I use it. If ALL communications go through this system it will probably get harder to follow what's going on.

Comment: The book tomislav recommended is pretty much a classic, you can't go wrong with it. I would say you already need a good knowledge of object oriented design to fully take advantage of reading it though.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to decouple the message sending and receiving process into an Observer - Listener structure. This is called the **Observer Pattern**. You can read more details about this pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). This will save you from dealing with multiple references and events as well as thinking about message send/receive implementation each time you need to add the communication to another class.

You can find more information on design patterns in the book [Design Patterns. Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://www.amazon.de/Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented-Software/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1358601484&sr=8-1).

Comment: Additional query as well. So, I can use the same Notification sort of globally to postNotifications from other objects as well? Let's say positing Notification from Fountain class for some other class. Is this also correct? P.S Can you recommend some text book where I can have a better idea while I write the programs to actually know what's good, bad or better?  But if I pass the notification references for now, would it be wrong to do that just to avoid going into observer implementations for now?

Comment: @user1240679 You need to somehow couple the observer-listener, and what I did so far was to keep references to the observer in the listener classes to make the interface simple: update() versus like a million update functions taking different arguments. These are two standard approaches to the problem "pushing" and "pulling" communications. With "pushing" you are giving arguments to the update method that are needed for the listener to update its state, with "pulling" you notify the listener who already stores ref to the observer to update itself. So far, I have used the pulling approach.